# C Word Occurrence

Tags: c

I've perused all of the related questions to quantifying the occurrence of a word in a text file and I'm still unable to get this to execute and count the words. I don't get an error but the output that is returned is:

File opened 
character count = 0 4195872

There are exactly 6 words "CORRESPONDENCE" in "file.txt", I just need the counter to return the value 6. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

    int counter;
    int ch;
    int str;

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen ("file.txt", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
            printf("File failed to open \n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("File opened \n");
            do {
                    str = fgetc(input);
                    //      if ((char*)str == keyword) counter++;                              
                    if (str == ch)counter++;
                    } while (str != EOF);

            printf("character count = %i %i\n", counter, ch );
                            fclose(input);
                }
         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: `ch` is never initialised.

Comment: In your line `if (str == ch)counter++;` you are just counting characters and not words. You have to count word by matching charater by character. Let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: When ch and counter are initialized this is the output: "File opened 
character count = 0 0"

Comment: Use `strcmp()` and `strncmp()` may help you a lot. Moreover if each line is seperate with a backspace (`\n`).

Comment: each word is on a new line. where would i use strcmp()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize your `ch` and counter variable. So they can be of any surprising values.
So it is not bizarre for you to get result 4194872.

Another critical error you make is that your program never actually get to count the occurrence of the word "correspondence". In your program, the variable str can only represent one alphabet, but not the word. So when you use `str == ch` to test if the word "correspondence" exist, you are actually testing if the **letter** equal to `c`.(And that is only true if you have correctly initialized your `str` variable. For clarity, it is better to declare `str` as a `char` type instead of type `int`).

The correct way to compare between *words* is to compare their letters one by one. If any letter doesn't fit, then return false.

Read this code to understand the comparing process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    FILE * file = fopen("file.txt","r");
    if(file == NULL) {printf("File not open"); return -1;}
    char* str ="correspondence"; //Declare str as an array and initiate it with your word
    char input[50];  //Declare an char array long enough to hold ordinary words
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",input) != EOF)
    {
            for(i = 0;i < strlen(str) && i < strlen(input) ;++ i)
            {
                    if(input[i] != str[i])  break;
                    else  i++;
            }
            if(i >= strlen(str) && strlen(str) == strlen(input))
            count++;
            memset(input,0,sizeof(input));
    }

    printf("word count = %d",count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, when the variables are initialized zero is returned. I've tried modifying the code changing str to char in order to read the string but there's an issue using fgetc and a char

Comment: You need to use fscanf to read a word. fgetc only reads a letter.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, I modified my code use fscanf and it works like a charm. :)

Comment: @user2821434 :) My pleasure to help. Please consider accepting my answer. You will gain a badge for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize ch before comparing.

Comment: when I initialize ch and counter I get 0 returned in the output.